# plain text file or encrypted file(C programming)

Tags: c, encryption, file-io

I have to write a code that accepts an input file , 
1)if it's a plain text file then it is encrypted and given a s output.
2)if it is an encrypted file it is de-crypted and given as output file.
How do i check if the input file is plain text or encrypted inside my code to run that particular method for it.

Comment: Not enough spec. You must already know the encryption method and file format in advance for this to be even possible, and if you know that, your question makes no sense.

Comment: it is supposed to accept the filename as command line argument, how would I know what file user inputs?

Comment: Again, without knowing what encryption method and file format you're using, nothing further can be done.

Comment: I am supposed to use Symmetric encryption and accept a .txt file

Comment: So you're rolling your own? Then you get to define the output format yourself as well, and if you're defining it, you can recognize it. Given the question, I'm not sure you're up to the task, and we can't be a school here, but good luck. When you actually try something and get stuck, then come back with more meaningful and specific questions.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question.Thanks anyway.

Comment: I understand it perfectly... you don't. You seem to believe that there is some way to determine whether a file is plaintext or encrypted. The the fact that you believe this shows you need more thought on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a command line option that says whether to encrypt or not

```
crypttool [-e|-d] <file>
```